# I am getting "This field is required." error on load of webpage when using the Django ModelForm

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I made a model called Annoucement in my models.py file as well as the form for it in my forms.py file. I then made the simple create view for it in my my views.py and made it show on the frontend using the django-crispy-forms package but anytime i load the website, the border of the field appears red showing that there is an error. I have tried checking what the error could be but I am not getting any luck around it.

[image: This is the image illustrating the problem]

models.py

```
class Announcement_by_dean(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ManyToManyField(add_students_by_manager)
    message = models.TextField()
    sent_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True)
    updated_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "message sent on "+ str(self.sent_date)
```

forms.py

```
class Annoucement_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Announcement_by_dean
        fields = ['student_id', 'message']
```

views.py

```
def dean_page(request):

    annoucement_list = Announcement_by_dean.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Annoucement_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, _("Message Sent Successfully!!!"))
            return redirect('dean_page')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _("Message Not Sent, Something is Wrong!!!"))
    else:
        form = Annoucement_form()
        messages.error(request, _("Invalid Method!!!"))

        context = {"form":form, "annoucement_list":annoucement_list}
        return render(request, "dean_page.html", context)
```

dean_page.html

```
<!-- Send Announcement -->
<div class="tab-pane fade show" id="nav-announcement" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-announcement-tab">
  <div class="container mt-4 p-3">
    <form action="{% url 'dean_page' %}" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form|crispy}}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Submit</button>
    </form>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: set `blank=True` on your TextField so that it may accept empty inputs.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem too efficient because the form is able to submit empty values into the database which is not what is required.

Comment: I figured out the issue, check the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, I realised that the indentation of my context and return render was the issue.

views.py

```
def dean_page(request):

    annoucement_list = Announcement_by_dean.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Annoucement_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, _("Message Sent Successfully!!!"))
            return redirect('dean_page')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _("Message Not Sent, Something is Wrong!!!"))
    else:
        form = Annoucement_form()

        context = {"annoucement_list":annoucement_list, "form":form}
        return render(request, "dean_page.html", context)
to 

def dean_page(request):

    annoucement_list = Announcement_by_dean.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Annoucement_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, _("Message Sent Successfully!!!"))
            return redirect('dean_page')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _("Message Not Sent, Something is Wrong!!!"))
    else:
        form = Annoucement_form()

    context = {"annoucement_list":annoucement_list, "form":form}
    return render(request, "dean_page.html", context)
```